# Handling variables defined in c file not header file

Tags: c

My unknown predecessor who has gone left codes. I try to use some of them, but his codes look unusual.

1.What he did is define variables in not a header but c file : **variables.c**

```
CHGR_CMD comand[MAX_COMANDS] __attribute__ ((section ("external"))); 
RAWDAT rawdat[MAX_RAWDAT] __attribute__ ((section ("external")));     
SC_TEST *curr_test[NUMCHANS];   /* array of pointers to current testrec */
SC_TESTSETUP chparam[NUMCHANS] __attribute__ ((section ("external")));  
SC_HOLDSTAT  stats[NUMCHANS] __attribute__ ((section ("external")));   
RAWDAT  *bufs[NUMCHANS]; 
//FACTS  control[NUMCHANS];  

short ntest;    
short new_dbuff;    
short start_err;    
short update_status;
long  status_sent;  
short load_done;    
char h_lok;   ....
```

2 init_vars() in another c file initializes above variables : **init_vars.c**

```
memset((char *) rawdat,0 ,sizeof(rawdat));
memset((char *) curr_test,0 ,sizeof(curr_test));
memset((char *) chparam,0 ,sizeof(chparam));
memset((char *) stats,0 ,sizeof(stats));
memset((char *) bufs,0 ,sizeof(bufs));

memset((char *) comand,0 ,sizeof(comand));
ntest = 0;
new_dbuff = 0;

start_err = 0;
```

3.call init_vars() in main.c

The first time I tried to include "variables.c" directly in init_vars.c, but it gave me below errors:

```
#10056 symbol "ad_lok" redefined: first defined in "./variables.obj"; redefined in "./init_vars.obj"    sCharger_Test_v1            C/C++ Problem
```

Not only ad_lok variable but also every variables defined in variables.c hit errors.

Changing variables.c to variables.h still gives me same errors.

How can I handles variables defined c file not header file?

Thanks

Comment: You have to make sure you include it exactly once - do this usually with an `#ifdef` type of construct, and defining a variable inside that. That way when the file is included a second time, it will be skipped. You see this in all header files - just open `stdio.h` for an example. Seems like terrible coding though.

Comment: You should *always* define variables in a .c file. You should only *declare* them in an .h file. `init_vars.c` +must* already (before any of your changes) see declarations of these variables, otherwise it would not compile. Therefore you need to find out and umderstand why exactly it sees these variables. Without this understanding your changes are bound to break things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `variables.c` does not declare variables or preprocessor macros, but actually *defines* these variables, you will need to make them `extern` in the "include" phase, and define them in a single file (say, `externs_definitions.c`).

For example:

**variables.h**

```
#ifndef VARIABLES_H
#define VARIABLES_H
extern CHGR_CMD comand[MAX_COMANDS] __attribute__ ((section ("external"))); 
extern RAWDAT rawdat[MAX_RAWDAT] __attribute__ ((section ("external")));     
extern SC_TEST *curr_test[NUMCHANS];   /* array of pointers to current testrec */
...
#endif /* VARIABLES_H_ */
```

Then leave variables.c as is.

Then in `init_vars.c`

```
#include "variables.h"
```

Further questions though; how does the code work currently? If `init_vars.c` doesn't directly include `variables.c` and there's no header file declaring them as `extern`, how does the existing code not fail the preprocessor trying to access undeclared variables?

Comment: Thank you for answering. To be honest, the left codes are not working. I just took over the project after getting thru a couple of guys. As I took over the project, they had gone already without leaving docs and comments.

Comment: Adding extern every variables in variables.h and leave variables.c doesn't fail compilation. I think, previous guy intended to put all variables used in other c files in one file, which is variables.c